# Can't access personal s3 server with boto3

Tags: amazon-s3, boto3

I have a private installation of a server which is fully s3-compatible. I have one bucket there and I can check it using s3 browser. I am trying to interact with the server using boto3 for python (using the same credentials that I use in s3 browser), however, for any request I get `NoSuchBucket` error. This is my code:

```
s3 = boto3.resource('s3', 
                    endpoint_url=hostname, 
                    use_ssl=False, 
                    aws_access_key_id=access_key, 
                    aws_secret_access_key=secret_key
                    )
for bucket in s3.buckets.all():
    print(bucket.name)
```

Initially I thought there was an issue with credentials, but then I was able to interact with the server through s3 browser client. 
So the problem is: I really don't understand the error code, since I am not querying any particular bucket. What could be the cause of the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved! It was a DNS resolution issue.